# JQuery: Remove 20th+ item

Tags: jquery

I am prepending a li to a ul every few seconds. I want to set the limit to 20 items. Once there are 20 items I want to remove the oldest item so that there is never more than 20 items. How can I do this in JQuery?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [gt](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/gt) selector to select everything after a specific element or the [lt](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/lt) for anything before. You'd have to use the length attribute of the array if you'll need to find out the existing length.

EG:

```
$('#ulID li:gt(19)').remove()
```

You can also use :first and :last if you're never inserting more than 1 item at a time.

Comment: This will leave 21 items in the list. Use `gt(19)` since it is a zero based index.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the last child do:

```
$('li:last-child').remove();
```

To remove the 20th child do (0 indexed)

```
$('li:eq(19)').remove();
```

Comment: +1 To be safe in case you have multiple `ul`, use a more specific selector. E.g.: `$('#theUL li:eq(19)')`

Answer (score 0):

After you prepend do the following...

```
//Assuming $ul = a jquery object that contains your ul element.
//If there are more than 20 items, remove oldest item
if ($ul.children().size() > 20) {
    $ul.children(":last-child").remove();
}
```

or if you have the li elements in a jquery object already, you can also do the following

```
if ($li.size() > 20) {
    $li.find(":last-child").remove();
}
```